# Searching Linux Files for a string (i.e.root credentials)

Tags: bash, grep

As a part of our audit policy. I need to search all files on a linux machine for any file that contains the root credentials.

This command will be run by a non-root account, thus, the result will include many "Permission denied" statements.

Any suggestion of the proper syntax to search all files ans filter the result to show useful links only !

I tried:
      grep - "root" / | grep "password"

However, as this command is run using non root accounts, the big part of the result is "permission denied"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission errors are outputed to `stderr`, so you could simply redirect that to `/dev/null/`. E.g.:

```
grep -R "root" . 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You would go:

```
grep -lir "root" /
```

The `-l` switch outputs only the names of files in which the text occurs (instead of each line containing the text), the `-i` switch ignores the case, and the `-r` descends into subdirectories.

#### EDIT 1:

As  running it as not root will be fine, as long as you're not trying to read other users' files.

#### EDIT 2:

To have only useful links, go with:

```
grep -lir -v "Permission denied" "root" /
```

The `-v` switch is for inverting the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Comment: but displaying the line itself is quite beneficial since I need to validate if its a false positive or not.

Answer (score 0):

> However, as this command is run using non root accounts, the big part
>   of the result is "permission denied"

Use `sudo` to run this `recursive grep`:

```
cd /home
sudo grep -ir 'root' *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the warnings with a redirection to /dev/null.

This solution uses find to walk the whole (accessible) filesystem :

```
find / -readable -exec grep -H root '{}' \; 2>/dev/null | grep password
```